# Kafka consumer don't receive messages after Spring-Cloud and Spring boot upgrade

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

After upgrading Spring Boot to version 3.1.0 and Spring Cloud to 2022.0.3, the Kafka consumer doesn't work, while the producer works fine. When testing on a lower version, it works.

Here are my producer properties in Service 1:

```
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        someBinding-out-0:
          destination: some_binding
          content-type: application/x-protobuf
```

I'm sending messages via a stream bridge. There are no problems at this moment.

Here are my consumer properties in Service 2:

```
  function:
   definition: someBinding
  bindings:
    someBinding-in-0:
      consumer:
        max-attempts: 1
        partitioned: true
        concurrency: 10
      destination: some_binding
      group: someBindingProcessingGroup
      content-type: application/x-protobuf
```

And here's the consumer code:

```
public Consumer<Message<SomeClass>> someBinding() {
    return someBinding -> {};
}
```

Comment: I've solved an issue
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2736

spring.cloud.stream.function.definition property is now removed in 4.x, and you must use spring.cloud.function.definition. Closing the issue, feel free to re-open if there is a need.

Comment: It would be better to add that as an answer; you will be able to accept a self-answer after a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

`spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` property is now removed in 4.x, and you must use `spring.cloud.function.definition`. (source: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream#2736](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2736))